# DataTables vertical page fitting on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design, datatables

Following the Vertical Page fitting blog on DataTables https://datatables.net/blog/2015-04-10, I'm trying to setup my table the same way but using the window resize event. Here's what i'm doing,

```
<script>
     var prevHeight = 0; //for storing the previous height of the window
     $(document).ready(function() {
            prevHeight = $(window).height(); //get the current height of the window on load
     });

     $(window).on('resize', function(e){
         var currentHeight = $(window).height(); //height of the window after resize
         var wrapper = $('.resize_wrapper'); //div containing the table
         var resizeStartHeight = wrapper.height(); //height of the wrapper

         var height = resizeStartHeight + (currentHeight - prevHeight); //new height for the wrapper
         if ( height < 180 ) { //setting a minimum height
             height = 180;
         }
         wrapper.height( height ); //set the new height for the wrapper
         prevHeight = $(window).height(); //store the new height of the window
     });

</script>
```

The table container is resizing, my table page length is changing. So far this code works but I can't seem to figure out what i'm missing because there's still a huge blank area under my table. There's nothing else under there, my table/div is the last element on the page.

[image: pageResize result]

Comment: I just had a brief look, but do you want to add or subtract here: `var height = resizeStartHeight + (etc...`?  Looks like subtract at first glance.

Comment: @wazz Well it depends, add or subtract will happen depending on the value of the `currentHeight - prevHeight`. If the window is made smaller, i.e. 1000 height turned to 500 then it would be `height = resizeStartHeight + (500 - 1000)` reducing the size of the table div wrapper.

Comment: Ah, `currentHeight` is after resize. Missed that.